# WSO2 IOTS: Unable to uninstall carbon feature

Tags: wso2

I follow [document here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon445/Uninstalling+Features):

> ### Uninstalling Features
>
> 1. Log in to the product's Management Console.
> 2. On the **Configure** menu, click **Features**.
> 3. Click **Installed Features**.
> 4. Select the features that you need to uninstall. If you wish to uninstall all the features, select the Select all in this page option.
> 5. Click **Uninstall**.
> 6. Verify the information and click **Next**.
>
> > If the uninstallation is successful, a success message will appear.

But when I click **Next**. I got **Error occurred while performing provisioning action**. Server log i posted here: http://pastebin.com/mS5vfSZs

Comment: Please post the code into SO. Your links could break in the future making this post non-informative.

Comment: Show us your full error message if you want any chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: sorry i will update it now

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this out I found out couple of bugs in feature uninstall which I reported and can be found at [1] & [2]. I assume you are performing something similar to the issue 3 that is been reported in [1]. Please track the jiras which will be resolved in a future IoT Server release.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IOTS-188

[2] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IOTS-189